# Add apps to Input Monitoring

Tags: macos, security, catalina, preferences

I would like to grant access for google chrome or safari to my microphone and both redirect me to security & privacy section.

There are no plus or minus signs and no apparent way to allow these apps to use my microphone.

I also tried the same with Skype. All of those apps just redirect to this blank preference pane.

[image: Input Monitoring]

How can I add an application here?

Comment: I think, usually apps (as stated) **request** input monitoring. Then they appear automatically in there. What are you trying to do? Are you writing your own software?

Comment: @letsiosManthos - you would want to choose another tab of the pane for microphone - this image and post is about keyboard control and not audio control. Perhaps a second question showing your audio section or adding that screen shot here will help?

Comment: Is this question really about `Microphone` and `Camera`? Not sure why Chrome or Safari would need Input Monitoring.

Comment: [How do I configure Camera and Microphone permission on macOS Mojave?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384310/18101)

Answer (score 1):

The core question here is **"What have you done to make / install any application that would request this entitlement?"**

A system call by an app you install and then run is what populates this preference pane. Additionally - there are several entitlements, so you might need to allow an app like Microsoft Teams several clicks for screen sharing, controlling the input, accessing the camera and microphone, etc...

I’ve found as I get used to this release, stating from the top of the pane and looking at each in sequence helps to get used to the different security restrictions.